# using "the" before "adjective + name of the country"

Tags: articles, definite-articles

Do I need to use "the" if I say "mysterious Japan" or "vast Russia"? Will it be "the mysterious Japan" or just "mysterious Japan"?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it is not advisable to say something like "The mysterious Japan" or "The vast Russia". For example, you have "The mysterious Japan". I suppose it won't take you long to recognize the problem if you just remove the adjective, which will be "The Japan" - There is no country such as "The Japan", right?

In your context, I suppose the appropriate way to use adjectives with country names is "The mysterious country of Japan" or "The vast land/country of Russia".

Comment: You've picked up on the facts that 'The mysterious Japan' is highly unidiomatic, but 'mysterious Japan' is also unidiomatic. Your alternative **is** idiomatic.